# Why is joins on a relation executing multiple queries in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've 3 tables: `biographies, affiliations, communities`

Affiliation belongs to biographies and communities, i.e. Affiliation has biography_id and community_ids as foreign keys, all with has_one relationships.  Biography is connected to community through affiliation

in rails console, when I execute:

```
b = Biography.joins(:affiliation => :community)
```

then, this is the sql output:

```
 Biography Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "biographies".* FROM "biographies" INNER JOIN "affiliations" ON "affiliations"."biography_id" = "biographies"."id" INNER JOIN "communities" ON "communities"."id" = "affiliations"."community_id" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

So far so good, continuing in the same console session, then I execute:

```
b.first.affiliation
```

Then, the output is:

```
D, [2019-04-06T23:21:20.417201 #38967] DEBUG -- :   Biography Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "biographies".* FROM "biographies" INNER JOIN "affiliations" ON "affiliations"."biography_id" = "biographies"."id" INNER JOIN "communities" ON "communities"."id" = "affiliations"."community_id" ORDER BY "biographies"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]

D, [2019-04-06T23:21:20.418180 #38967] DEBUG -- :   Affiliation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "affiliations".* FROM "affiliations" WHERE "affiliations"."biography_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["biography_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

First: Why is it doing another join, shouldn't it have used the join from the first activerecord query?

second: Why is there another select log?  Shouldn't it use the result from join instead of a new select?

Continuing, when I execute:

```
b.first.affiliation.community
```

then, it ends up outputting another log of selecting from communities.

Is it actually running a brand new query, or is it just getting it from result stored in memory from the first one?  And how do I tell real vs memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` in your first query is an inner join: it tells ActiveRecord to only load biographies for which there are affiliations with a community.

If you want to access these records and avoid a N+1 query, you can either use an additional [`includes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) statement or use [`eager_load`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-eager_load).

So yes: any time you see the console outputting a SQL statement, it means that a new query is being run.

Answer (score 0):

`b = Biography.joins(:affiliation => :community)` means get all `Biographies` that have `affiliation` made by `community` which mean that you are loading subset of `Biographies` based on `inner join` condition(parent table should have at least one reference in the association table).

If you want to `preload` whole results, you can use:

`b = Biography.preload(:affiliation => :community)`